# Changes to my classes in Eclipse are not reflected when I run the project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I recently wiped my disk, but I have numerous backups of all Eclipse-related files. Everything that I need seems to be here, but whenever I make changes to my classes, even after I quit and restart Eclipse, the changes aren't reflected when I run the program. The changes still have been saved in my .java files, but they don't get compiled when I run.

Things I have done:

- Project > Clean (numerous times)
- Project > Build Automatically is checked
- I tried building manually several times to no avail
- All my hot code replace options are enabled
- Downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse
- Restored my old Eclipse folder from before the wipe

I should be using the same settings as before, back when everything worked, and I haven't changed any operating procedures. The project is a simple game, nothing outside the box. I checked the build path, the only things there are the old class files.

So that's my situation. Thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts : Everything happens for a reason. A computer does not misbehave unless you do something. Do the changes that you make get a chance to execute? For example : You put an SOP in an if condition that is never satisfied.

Comment: When you say they are not reflected in your runtime what runtime are you referring to. It may be that a deployment step is not taking place.

Comment: First of all, what kind of project? Console app? Web app? Are you using Maven? Details, please!

Comment: Check the build path.  Is there an old jar file?

Comment: updated to include your information

Comment: Check "Problems" view for that project. There might be some information why the project cannot be built. Also, is Java Builder enabled for it (Project properties->Builders)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the reasoning behind why it happens, but a quick fix is to copy the class to a separate project, then copy it back.  Fixed the issue for me.